# React Native Android gelocation: watchPosition does not react to location service turning on/off

Tags: android, geolocation, react-native

If location service was turned off initially `watchPosition` is not called when it was turned on. As a workaround I am calling recursively `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` if an error occurred.

Also `watchPosition` is not called when location service was turned off.

On iOS everything works as expected.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated

Tested on Galaxy Note 5 (Android 6.0.1) and different AVD emulators, react-native v0.33

`android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` is included in AndroidManifest.xml

```
initialGeolocation(){
    delete this.androidLocation;
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        (position) => {
            log('LOCATION getCurrentPosition success', position);  
            deviceActions.geolocation(position);
        },
        (error) => {
            log('LOCATION getCurrentPosition error', error.message || error);
            if (Platform.OS == 'android'){
                this.androidLocation = setTimeout(this.initialGeolocation, 500);
            }
        }, 
        {
            enableHighAccuracy: (Platform.OS == 'android') ? false : true, 
            timeout: 10000, 
            maximumAge: 500
        }
    );
},   

componentDidMount() {
    this.initialGeolocation();
    this.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
        (position) => {
           log('LOCATION watchPosition success', position);
           deviceActions.geolocation(position);
        },
        (error) => {
            log('LOCATION watchPosition error', error.message || error);
        },
        {
            enableHighAccuracy: (Platform.OS == 'android') ? false : true, 
            distanceFilter: 10, 
            timeout: 10000, 
            maximumAge: 500
        }
    );
}
```